# Generate a prettier plot with the data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for all prettier ways to represent my data in any plots. I hope can get more suggestions so that I can learn and note as reference. So please do provide me with more examples of any idea you have. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"label":["a","b","c","d"],
                "value1":[2,4,6,8],
                 "value2":[11,12,13,14],
                 "value3":[5,6,7,8]})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(a.label, a.value1, "r--", linewidth=5, label="a") 
plt.plot(a.label, a.value2, "b-", linewidth=5, label="b")
plt.plot(a.label, a.value3, "g-", linewidth=5, label="c")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Above is my plot. But it is not really that nice though.

Comment: How about setting `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))` and `linewidth=2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#only if use jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline
a = pd.DataFrame({"label":["a","b","c","d"],
                "value1":[2,4,6,8],
                 "value2":[11,12,13,14],
                 "value3":[5,6,7,8]})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

ax=plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(a.label, a.value1, "r--", linewidth=5, label="a") 
plt.plot(a.label, a.value2, "b-", linewidth=5, label="b")
plt.plot(a.label, a.value3, "g-", linewidth=5, label="c")
#grid on
plt.grid()
#change size of legend
ax.legend(fontsize=20)
#hiding upper and right axis layout
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
#changing the thickness
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)
#size of axes
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
#setlabels
plt.show()
```

Image Output:
[image]